# Is storing Surge information a breach of Uber's API Terms of Use?

Tags: uber-api

Looking to build an app that monitors the surges in specific areas. Those areas will be stored, and Ubers API will be periodically called to search for Surges in that area.

Is this any of breach of Ubers API Terms of Use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/terms-of-use specifically the prohibition here: Do not "Store or aggregate Uber's data". Thanks for checking!

Also replied on Twitter to this question here: https://twitter.com/Stonesam92/status/811243667138691074